# How to force MinGW to recompile everyhing

Tags: mingw

Normaly MinGW (GCC C Compiler) recompiles only files that have beeen changed. But I fear this does not work properly. So I wan't to recompile everything at each "Compile All" or "Compile Project". Is there any option to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First run a make clean command and then a make command. I think that the MinGW make is called mingw32-make.exe

Answer (score 1):

Use -B switch to make, whose long form is --always-make